# Parse txt using php

Tags: php, parsing

I have txt file which looks like

```
Name: Long valueName2: Long loooooooong valueName3: short value
```

I need to parse it and insert to a database which looks like this

```
_____________________________________________________
|id  |Name        | Name2               |Name3      |
|1   |Long value  |Long loooooooong     |short value|
------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I do this? Is it any standard function in PHP. Or I need to use regex, if yes which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$text = "Name: Long valueName2: Long loooooooong valueName3: short value";
$values = preg_split('/Name\d{0,1}\: /', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

You can then insert `$values[0]`, `$values[1]`, `$values[2]`

Comment: I think this returns 4 matches where $values[0] is empty. Maybe it should be `$values = preg_split('/Name\d{0,1}\: /', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Comment: @Thefourthbird you are right, I did not run before posting, my bad. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll update my answer.